# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR')

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I was using Java 6 to connect to IBM MQ. In Java 6 as SSL V3 is not disable we are able to connect to IBM MQ.

Now I want to migrate to Java 8 where SSL V3 is in the list of disabled algorithms. which gives me an error `"WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR')".`

If I remove the SSL V3 from the list of disabled algorithms it works but I do not want to do that. I want TLS to be supported when connecting to IBM MQ.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So can you show us the code you are using to make the connection, specifically where you set the algorithm to be used, as that is what you would need to change to say you wanted to use a TLS instead of an SSL V3 algorithm,

Comment: Are you using a IBM JRE or a Oracle JRE?

Comment: @JoshMc,
I am getting the same error.
While i run the program using main method it works fine but if i run this using server then i get above mentioned error.What changes should be done?

Comment: @RockingDev what version of java do you use when running standalone vs server?

Comment: @JoshMc,i am using Java 7 only at both places.

Comment: Do you have strong cryptography provider enabled in both places?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [1].  You will have to generate the appropriate keys in your keystore/truststore for the desired cipher.  You will have to change the desired cipher in your code.  From an MDBs activation spec:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "sslCipherSuite", propertyValue = "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"),
```

In some configuration for your IBM artifacts, you will have "sslCipherSuite".  This needs to be set accordingly.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm